# iOS: Sign In with Google button

Tags: ios

I am new to `iOS` development and working on a project where I want my users to login with Google.

I worked my way through Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started), and could login in as well. All now I wanted was button/image which says "Sign in with Google" as
[image]
I looked through Google's SDK, but there is no exact image like that. so I tried to create my own which looks like

[image]
where `ImageView` is replaced with image in Google'e SDK.

**Problem**
When I run this, this doesn't look like it should

[image]

The red color of image and button do not match, neither I see vertical black line.

**Question**
a.) Where can I find the "Sign in with Google" button for `iOS`?
b.) The downloaded png might not work since as per the device we need two different resolutions `@1x` and `@2x`

Please let me know how can I get it?

**UPDATE**
- The problem was that the `GooglePlus.bundle` was not correctly loaded in my project. After fixing it, I see a button, but no text like

[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an image that looks like this, just use the following code instead of that button and this will create a button as well as its action which will perform Google+ SSO for you.

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;

//signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

// You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step

signIn.clientID = kClientId;

// Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope
//signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope

// Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
signIn.delegate = self;
```

Just add the **signIn** button to your view and it should work. Here is the link in case you need any help

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: My `SSO` integration is working correctly as I mentioned. All I care at the moment is the button/image view

Comment: you can get the image as well directly from SDK try this method.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question, may be you know why I see that issue

Comment: I fixed that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511134/ios-google-button-does-not-work-from-xib-file