# iOS: Google+ button does not work from XIB file?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I asked [iOS: Sign In with Google button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490620/ios-sign-in-with-google-button) yesterday and still struggling. The answer I got helped me figure out that the `GooglePlus.bundle` was imported incorrectly.

Now I am stuck on the part that the button that I created via `XIB` file, doesn't shows up on the page.

**What I did?**
I added a new button as per this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5756364), and validated if everything works fine. The code looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GPPSignInButton *button = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
    [button setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;


    [self.signInButton setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];


    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[@"profile"];
    signIn.delegate = self;
//    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

}
```

When I run it, I see
[image]

So button added manually works, but not the one I created with `xib`. My `xib` looks like
[image]

and in `GooglePlusLoginViewController.h` the code looks like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

@class GPPSignInButton;

@interface GooglePlusLoginViewController : UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate>
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;
@end
```

I want to learn what mistake I am doing, can someone spot that?

Thanks

Comment: did you add GPPSignInButton to your button in Class in identity inspector??

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad way to do it. If you look at your output closely, the blue button still remains in the background. This is because, you have added `UIButton` in your `storyboard`/`xib` and you've hooked them up in your `ViewController.h` file.

Then you are creating new instance of `GPPSignInButton` and adding it back into the `UIButton` you've previously created.

You should not create button within button.

Btw, I ran into the same problem today, and here is how I solved it.

I programmatically created `GPPSignInButton` and positioned it programmatically within the `view`.

Add this in your `viewDidLoad` in your `ViewController.m`

```
GPPSignInButton *button = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
[button setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];

CGRect frame = button.frame;
frame.origin.x = 50;
frame.origin.y = 190;
button.frame = frame;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Being new to `iOS`, I am not sure if this is the correct practice, but the following changes that I did worked for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GPPSignInButton *button = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
    [button setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];
    [self.signInButton addSubview:button];

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;

    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[@"profile"];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];

}
```

and it showed up as
[image]